# If $n\Delta s_n=o(1)$ is satisfied then $n\log n \Delta s_n=o(1) $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers. I wonder if  $n\Delta s_n=o(1)$  is satisfied then $n\log n \Delta s_n=o(1) $ is also satisfied.

$(\Delta s_n= s_n-s_{n-1})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $s_n=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac 1{k\log k}, n\ge 2.$ Then $\Delta s_n=\frac 1{n\log n},n\ge 3.$ Thus $n\Delta s_n=\frac{1}{\log n}=o(1).$ But then we have that $n\log n\Delta s_n=1\ne o(1).$

Comment: Thank you also are there any example such that $n\log n \Delta s_n=o(1)$ but $n\Delta s_n \neq o(1)$